# Github Actions $GITHUB_OUTPUT, Error: Invalid Format without any multiline strings

Tags: github-actions

I am trying to write a Github Action that outputs the result of a `curl` HTTP call to a JSON endpoint processed with `jq` to the output of that step, like so:

```
      - name: Get existing Neon branch for this PR
        id: get-existing-branch
        run: |
          echo "branch_id=$(
            jq --raw-output '.branches[] | select(.name | startswith("PR #${{ inputs.pr-number }} ")).id' list-neon-branches-response.json
          )" >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
Error: Unable to process file command 'output' successfully.
Error: Invalid format 'br-shrill-unit-918412'
```

I see a number of issues that generally tell people that they're doing it wrong for multiline strings, but that's where I'm stumped - this isn't multiline. Any ideas? Some source code:

- [Action runthrough where it failed](https://github.com/osdiab/personal-website/actions/runs/5342644188/jobs/9684712171)
- [Source of the workflow](https://github.com/osdiab/personal-website/blob/62000f1304812776d675bda08c7bdb70209d09f8/.github/workflows/delete-neon-pr-branch.yml)

Thanks all!

Comment: Did you try combining that into one line? Example: `echo "branch_id=$(jq -r '.branches[] | select(.name | startswith("PR #${{ inputs.pr-number }}")).id' list-neon-branches-response.json)" >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"`

Comment: Or, you can set the variable in a separate line and then set it as an output parameter in the next i.e. `branch_id=$(jq -r '.branches[] | select(.name | startswith("PR #${{ inputs.pr-number }}")).id' list-neon-branches-response.json` and then `echo "branch_id=$branch_id" >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"`

Comment: Lol silly me, I guess the new lines in the sub shell conmand did make it have new lines. It works now!

Answer (score 0):

I changed it to this:

```
      - name: Get existing Neon branch for this PR
        id: get-existing-branch
        run: |
          branch_id="$(jq --raw-output '.branches[] | select(.name | startswith("PR #${{ inputs.pr-number }} ")).id' list-neon-branches-response.json)"
          echo "Branch ID: $branch_id"
          echo "branch_id=$branch_id" >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"
```

And now it’s happy. Welp.